# Mongo DB Update Whole Document and Increment Version

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoDB to implement a JSON document store which makes use of *optimistic locking* to deal with concurrent updates.

To implement *optimistic locking* I have added a `_version` property to my documents; this tracks the number of times the document has been updated. A caller will pass in the `_version` of the document that they have modified. If the `_version` doesn't match the current database version they will get an error.

To update the `_version` and the document I make use of the [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify) method.

```
/* Get JSON into a DBObject
 - remove _version as we can't increment and set it at the same time 
*/
val content = JSON.parse( json ).asInstanceOf[DBObject].remove("_version")

// Query to find the expected current version of the document
val query = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("_id", myId).append("_version", versionNo).get()

// Update object - set the content and increment the version counter
val update = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$set", content).append("$inc",  BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$version", 1).get()).get()

/* Update the document, 
   increment the version 
   and return the updated document, 
   if the document does not exist then create a new one

   Params: Query, Fields, Sort, Remove, Update, Return New, Upsert
*/
val updatedDBObj = db.getCollection( myCollection ).findAndModify( query, null, null, false, doc, true, true )
```

This works pretty well, however `$set` will only **add/update** values and will not **remove** keys that have been removed from the document.

Is there a way to replace the whole document **and** to also increment the version number in a single DB operation? I'm not particular keen on having to to diff the documents to work out what to add `$set` and what to remove `$unset`.

Comment: Not really. But can you live with putting all the data you want to replace under a single root key? i.e `{ "data": { }, "_version": 1 }`. That way all subkeys are within "data" and you just `$set` "data".

Comment: @BlakesSeven excellent a nice simple solution which has solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit out of the box. But as I said *"If you can live with that"* it just makes things simple.